# NGINX + Angular-9 - Router removes the URL segment

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, angular-router

We have an Angular 9 application that's behind a NGINX reverse proxy. An example NGINX proxy routes are as below:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
}

location /abc {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
}

location /xyz {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
}
```

The application reads the segment in the URL and decides to load theme assets based on `/` or `/abc` or `/xyz` part of the URL.

However, once the Angular application is loaded, we notice that the segment `/abc` or `/xyz` is removed from the URL.

Is there a way to retain this segment of the URL?

Comment: Exactly the same thing is happening to me...did you ever manage to solve it?